# biztalk Outbound Logical not shown in biztalk Admin on deployment

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-deployment

> Biztalk "Outbound Logical Port" not shown in biztalk Admin on deployment.

Hi, I am trying to deploy an application where there is a receive and Send. When I deploy this application, receive port is shown (i.e "Inbound Logical Port"), but Send Port (i.e "Outbound Logical Port") is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

This might occur if your logical port uses **Direct Binding**. In this case, there is no facility to configure it in the admin console because the message goes straight to the message box!

HTH

Comment: Hi Amas, The Binding was configured as "I'll Specify Later" . could you please suggest where can i check for this Direct Binding

Comment: Hi Varshil, Is the port a "Receive-Send" port? Because if it is, then in the admin console it will only show the Inbound logical Port. I'm assuming that we are talking about an orchestration?